# How to dynamically add authguard based on a role in Angular?

Tags: angular, rbac, auth-guard

In my Angular app , Admin user creates other users and roles.

While creating the roles , Admin can add permissions to it . i.e what menu items can this type of user role can access ?

The challenging part is that , I need to specify auth guard to the routes .

For example ,

**Supervisor role type can access - Menu item 1 Menu Item 2 , Menu item 4, Menu item 5**

**Engineer role type can access - Menu Item 3 , Menu Item 6**

All the menu items are separate modules .

When an Engineer tries to access menu item 1 via URL , he should be redirected .

Please help me on this . Any high level approach is fine for me . Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a clean way to manage permissions based on roles, i suggest that you use **ngx-permissions**

```
npm i ngx-permissions
```

NgxPermissionsGuard implements CanLoad interface, and you can use it like this

```
 {
  path: 'lazy',
  data: {
   permissions: {
     only: 'SUPERVISOR',
   }
  },
  canLoad: [NgxPermissionsGuard],
  loadChildren: 'app/lazy-module/lazy-module.module#LazyModule'
},
```

if you want to grant access to something except Supervisor you can use **except**

```
data: {
   permissions: {
     except: 'SUPERVISOR',
   }
},
```

Both possibilities is possible too

```
 data: {
  permissions: {
    only: ['ADMIN', 'MODERATOR'],
    except: ['SUPERVISOR']
  }
}
```

More details [here](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions)

if you don't want to use ngx-permission you can create a service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanLoad {
 constructor(private router: Router) {}

 canLoad(route: Route): boolean {

 let url = route.path; //get url here, example menu1
 // get permissions array here from a service or localstorage
 if(permissions.indexOf(url) !== -1 ) { //means it exist
   return true
 }
 return false; 
 }
}
```

and add it in your 3 routes

```
 {path: "menu1", loadChildren:'./main/menu.module#Menu1Module', canLoad:[AuthGuardService]}
 ...
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your answer.We can definitely manage permissions in a clear way.One point where I'm stuck is that,on a successful log in,server will send the below response 
`{
  username: 'harry',
  role: 'manager',
  permissions: ['menu 1','menu 2','menu 3'] // these are all side menu items 
}`
The role is dynamic and we cannot hardcode the data(SUPERVISOR) as below .
`data: {
   permissions: {
     only: 'SUPERVISOR',
   }
}`

 Admin can even create a role named 'DUMMY' and assign some side menus to it . Could you please help me how I can achieve that? Thanks once again :)